# Spark/Python - getting back IP address.

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark. I have the master(192.168.33.10), and slave(192.168.33.12) cluster setup locally, and I'm wrote to following script to demo that both master and slave are running the get_ip_wrap() on its own machine.

However, when I run with the command `./bin/spark-submit ip.py`, I only see the `192.168.33.10` in the output, I was expecting `192.168.33.12` in the output as well.

```
['192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10', '192.168.33.10']
```

Am I missing something here?

```
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

def get_ip_address(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
        s.fileno(),
        0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR                                                                                                               
        struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
    )[20:24])

def get_ip_wrap(num):
    return get_ip_address('eth1')

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
distData = sc.parallelize(data)

result = distData.map(get_ip_wrap)
print result.collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say `conf = SparkConf().setAppName('appName').setMaster('local')` you're explicitly telling spark to run in local mode. This means the application is running single threaded on the master node.

To fix it, get rid of the `.setMaster('local')` call, and do something like `.setMaster('yarn')` instead (if yarn is your cluster manager). See here for your options: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls.

Alternatively, you can launch the `spark-submit` bin with the `--master` option. This is what the docs seem to suggest that you do, but if I remember correctly I think you can set the master in the application (but maybe not, I can't test it right now).